Accessibility fix for a transparent navigation overlaying a hero image with white text - WordPress
I am facing this contrast error using WAVE - Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool https://wave.webaim.org/ on my navgation links in various websites. This error is specifically happening when I try to overlay a transparent navigation header over a hero that contains an image or a video. An example of the error is below. I've tried making the hero background contrast worthy (dark) and this seemed to have no effect.
Here is my template site with an image below to show what I mean https://slynntemplates.wpenginepowered.com/test/
enter image description here
Though Lighthouse seemed to have a better outcome, I am wondering if there is a fairly easy work around this error. Some of our clients use WAVE.

Your body has a background color of #f2f2f2. Your image element (.fl-node-rhu16pal243o > .fl-row-content-wrap) does have a background-color of black, but that element is a sibling element to your nav element. WAVE may not be able to associate the background-color for the image div with the content of the header section. Applying a background-color: black to the body satisfies WAVE’s contrast requirements for the navbar. There’s an issue with the footer icons, but changing to black icons or a darker red (e.g. #B50003) may fix that (although the current red seems to be a logo color).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
